# Reset global database username and password

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a global database, name - ABN,  Username - ABNTEST and password - abntest123.

This password expired and all system default passwords have also expired. Some usernames and passwords for the system have been forgotten.

How can I connect to the ABD database?

---

I'm getting the error below while connecting to my database:

```
ERROR:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 1024 in tablespace SYSTEM
ORA-28001: the password has expired
```

How can resolve this error?

Comment: You can connect as SYS from the server the database is installed upon. Do you have access to this?

Comment: as @ben suggested , you can also loggin as admin to the server and connect as sysdba without a password, like this `sqlplus / as sysdba`

Answer (score 1):

1) login to Oracle's operating system with Oracle's credentials.

If it is UNIX/Linux you can use Putty programme.

2) From the command line run the following command:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

(If you do not have the credentials you have to ask your DBA or SYSADMIN to do that.)

3) after you are connected change the user's password, i.e.:

```
ALTER USER abntest IDENTIFIED BY abntest123;
```

Sometimes passwords cannot repeat itself than you have to change it to something else.

*Tip for future: There is one good open source software to keep passwords: "Password Gorilla"*

Comment: With regard to your tip: Really? Are there no other good open source password managers?